# Django executes second request before returning the first one

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am sending two PATCH queries from my front end to Django immediately one after the other. Both queries reach the same django REST framework endpoint (see below).

My problem is the order in which things happen. The following code gives me this print:

```
FIRST PATCH: clearing
SECOND PATCH HAPPENING
FIRST PATCH: after adding references
```

So as you can see, the second patch is being execute in the middle of the first one. Which causes it to return an instance where the references field is empty as it has not been repopulated yet.

```
 def partial_update(self, request, pk=None, *args, **kwargs):
    if 'height' in data or 'pos_x' in data:
        # do something             
        print("SECOND PATCH HAPPENING")
        return super(NodeViewSet, self).partial_update(request, *args, **kwargs)

    reference_ids = request.data.get('references', None)
    if reference_ids is not None:
        references = Node.objects.filter(pk__in=reference_ids)
        instance = self.get_object()

        print("FIRST PATCH: clearing")

        instance.references.clear()
        instance.references.add(*references)

        print("FIRST PATCH: after adding references")

    return super(NodeViewSet, self).partial_update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Why is this happening? How can I ensure that the Second PATCH doesn't happen in the middle of the first one?

Comment: How are you sending those requests? If you want them to always execute sequentially, you should send them synchronously rather than asynchronously.

Comment: Those are jquery Ajax requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not control this on the server side, even if you send a request after sending another one, you have no control over which will execute first. They depend on many things, including to which process they are assigned on the server machine, the network path the packages travel, etc.

If you want to ensure that a request is sent after another one completes, you need to ensure this on the client side. Something like the following, with jquery ajax:

```
$.ajax({
        url : 'url',
        type : 'PATCH',
        data : data,
        success : function(response, textStatus, jqXhr) {
            // Issue the second request here, after the first one is completed successfully
            $.ajax({
                url : 'url',
                type : 'PATCH',
                data : data,
                success: function(response, textStatus, jqXhr) {
                    // Both requests succeeded here, issued sequentially
                }
            }
        },
        error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            ...
        }
});
```

Comment: To be honest, the order in which these queries are handled is not as important as the fact that the second one does not happen right in the middle of the first one. Any idea why that happens?

Comment: @RyanPergent that's caused by concurrency. If your django application is not served on a single process / single thread, which is almost never the case for production deployments, requests are handled concurrently. So while your first request waits for reading data from the db for example, your second request arrives and gets executed on another process or thread. This could be the other way around as well. You shoud not build your application with the assumption that you will be serving one request at a time